# what language uses [% %]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning programming and am inspecting code on websites.  I've learned a handful of things but I don't recognize the [%  and  %] in this code.  What are these things?

```
<div class="comment comment_inner">
[% if (data.comment.id) { %]
  <a href="#" class="collapse_toggle"></a>
[% } %]

<div class="by">
  [% if (data.view.hasProfilePicture()) { %]
    <a href="[%= data.comment.user.profile_url %]">
      <img src="[%= data.comment.user.profile_image %]" alt="[%= data.comment.user.display_name %]" />
    </a>
  [% } %]

[% if (data.comment.user.membership && data.comment.user.membership.short_bio) { %]
    <div class="name_container has_flair">
  [% } %]
```

Comment: this looks like a templating language, you should say more about this project, which libraries, etc you are using, for what..??

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm new but I want to learn how to write a comment section.  This is from the comment section on theverge.com.

Comment: it could be anything allowing custom delimeters, ex mustache.js...

Comment: proprietary garbage templates

Comment: @gofastrocket, this is not a good beginner learning resource, try to learn at some other place, what you want, and come back with questions, while learning, yep

Comment: I think it's one of these template languages.  Twig looks a little like it.  Thanks all for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be replaced with any other non-alphanumeric characters and non-printing characters see Please Simple things about Ruby and Rails here https://simpleror.wordpress.com/